# How to Proxy using Node using express-http-proxy to strip final rest

Tags: node.js, express, npm, http-proxy

On my local JavaScript, I want to make a rest call to

```
/rest/speakers
```

and have that proxied to

```
http://localhost:2011/rest/speakers
```

I have code as follows that does not quite work as I want:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = require('express')();
app.use('/rest', proxy('localhost:2011/'));
app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 8081');
});
```

To make the proxy work, I actually need to call

```
/rest/rest/speakers
```

I kind of get it.  It seems that I'm proxying my `/rest` to the root of `localhost:2011` and then I need to dive into the `/rest` of that server.  Adding `/rest` to the end of the `proxy(..)` is ignored.

Comment: Can't you map `app.use('/rest', proxy('localhost:2011/rest'));` as such?

Comment: Sadly no.  It ignores everything after the proxiee url base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using proxyReqPathResolver to modify your URL as needed.

```
var url = require('url'),
    proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

// ... other app setup here 

app.use('/rest', proxy('localhost:2011', {
    proxyReqPathResolver: function(req, res) {
      return '/rest/rest' + url.parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));
```